# How to have local Git repositories in Atifactory?

Tags: git, artifactory

Is it possible to have local Git repository in Artifactory?

One way could be we can zip the Git repository folder and upload it to the Artifactory. But the problem is we will not have the updated zip file every time because we should zip it manually.

Comment: What could be the point of getting these zip files if their content can be obtained directly from git?

Comment: @user7860670 I want it on artifactory

Comment: @meenasushanth: why? This smells like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) that's very likely to have a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory is a binary manager and your use case does not seem to be fitting in here.
Once the developers finish the implementation, they will push the code GIT source code. Upon a successful build, the final output (it can be a war/jar/ear etc) will be pushed to Artiactory. Artifactory's functionality is to manage that output (binary) and its versions. Saving the source code by zipping it on Artifactory does not fit in here.

If you would like to save the code as it is on Artifactory, it is still possible, where artifactory treats as a raw file(without metadata) and you can upload the entire folder as it is using [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles). Be informed, if there is any change on your code, that does not get reflected on Arifactory. You may need to sync the files periodically.